# Identify the running service in Tomcat which use 100% cpu usage

Tags: tomcat, cpu-usage

My web-based Java EE application is based on the following technology:

- Frame Work: Struts 2.0
- Server: Tomcat 6.0
- Front UI: JSP, JSTL/Struts tag, HTML
- Database: Microsoft SQL Server 9.00.2047.00
- Language: Core java, XML, XSLT.

Right now I'm facing the problem that some process of my web application will consume more CPU usage. Sometimes my Tomcat server will use 100% cpu; that's why my PC hangs. I can't identify which process will cause this 100% cpu usage.

Right now I'm looking for any third party application or any utility which provides me the CPU usage information details with name of running process (service), which is running in Tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for a Java Profiler... I've heard good things about HPROF (takes a little time to get used to, but should provide all the information you need (and it's free).  Here are some instructions on HPROF provided by sun.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html

I haven't personally run it on a server, but I have associates who have to identify problems very much like yours - it should give you what you need.

Also bear in mind that observing the processes will change the performance of the processes - so this isn't something to run in production. See [Observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))

Comment: hi Nick Rippe, first of thanks for the reply, can you help me to how can i use HPROF with j2ee based web application [which deployed in tomcat]

Comment: The exact instructions will vary by operating system and such - but generally, you're going to want to add the -agentlib:hprof[=options] to your environment variables (follow instructions in first link for configuration).  Here's some more detail (linux specific): http://www.coderanch.com/t/432949/Performance/java/Tomcat-Heap-Dump-SOLVED